# Load external Javascript before skin Javascript in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9, magento-layout-xml, layout-xml

I'm trying to add the Google Maps Javascript API to my Magento module.

The problem I'm having is that the `core/text` block that I am including, that contains the external Javascript inclusion tag, only ever appears after all of the `addJs` actions.

This means the script I have in `pvtl_stores.js` that targets the `google` object doesn't work as the `google` object hasn't been initialized yet.

Here is my `local.xml` file:

```
<layout>
<default>
    <reference name="head">

        <block type="core/text" name="google.maps" before="root">
            <action method="setText">
                <text><![CDATA[<script src="//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>]]></text>
            </action>
        </block>

        <action method="addItem">
            <type>skin_js</type>
            <name>js/pvtl_stores.js</name>
        </action>

    </reference>
 </default>
</layout>
```

Is there a way to have the `core/text` block load before the `addJs` actions?

By the way, if it isn't obvious by the question, I'm new to Magento programming!

Comment: have you tried `before="-"` to render at very first ?

Comment: I have tried this, it did nothing. I'm pretty sure it will only order text blocks within a text list but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

upload you Js in `root\js` folder. And call this code in your `app\design\frontend\base\default\template\page\html\head.phtml` file at top.

```
<?php echo Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_JS)."/yourjs.js"; ?>
```

or just direct call that

```
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

***UPDATE***

You have to download the js first then
go to `app\design\frontend\rwd\default\layout` `page.xml` (if you are using default theme otherwise go to `yourtheme\default\layout`) and you js here

```
    <block type="page/html_head" name="head" as="head">
            <action method="addJs">
               <script>yourjs/yourjs.js</script>
           </action>

            <action method="addJs">
               <script>prototype/prototype.js</script>
           </action>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I probably should've been more specific in my question. I have already hard coded the script tag in my template file but this felt too... hackery(?). Not sure if this is good practice or not. I know Magento is picky with what files are edited etc. I did, at least, only put the script tag in my theme. I didn't modify the base or default themes.